# CJSON::encode with New Line (\n)

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to add a new line `\n` to `CJSON::encode`, but It's adding another `\` that ignores the command.
What should I do to `CJSON::encode` release `\n`?

Code:

```
CJSON::encode(array('error'=>'First Line\nSecond Line'))
```

Return:

```
{"error":"First Line\\nSecond Line"}
```

What I want:

```
{"error":"First Line\nSecond Line"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, not really a yii issue.

You simply cannot put new lines in a string using simple quotes :

http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

You should try :

```
CJSON::encode(array('error'=>"First Line\nSecond Line"))
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer. =)